# apply styleSheet to datatips of ColumnChart control in flex

Tags: css, apache-flex

how can i apply styleSheet to datatips of ColumnChart control in flex?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a css file bounded to your application you write:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
@namespace chartClasses "mx.charts.chartClasses.*";

chartClasses|DataTip {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-style: inset;
    /*specify the styles you want*/
}
```

or inside your application, between `<fx:Style>[..]</fx:Style>` tags.